# RegEx for decimal number with maximum length Zero not woking

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex to have a number only stat from 1  and max length without decimal 10,
I try this regex `^[1-9]{1,10}([,.][0-9]{0,2})?$`

now facing issue after type 1 zero not accepting.

Comment: Because you are only allowed to input `1-9` for the number before the floating point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might write the pattern as starting with `[1-9]` and repeat 0-9 times a digit `[0-9]` for the total of 10 digits.

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,9}([,.][0-9]{0,2})?$
```